# Javascript causing form to break in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

**Objective:** Understand a Javascript related IE compatibility problem.

**Question:** Why does my Javascript break in IE and nowhere else (besides "IE sucks," haha) and is there an easy fix.

**Details:** I have a payment system that allows the user to select between 3 payment methods (via html radio buttons) and uses Javascript to display the appropriate form to complete payment. In chorme and firefox it works perfectly.

In IE however, once the initial radio button is clicked and the Javascript displays the appropriate div the cursor jumps to the lower middle of the page and the user cannot click on any of the input boxes in the form.

The boxes can be reached if the user right clicks on them, but not easily. There are a variety of ways I can get around this, but I'm trying to understand what *causes* the problem in IE. Especially if it's poor coding on my part. Also, if there is an easy fix to the existing code I'd be interested in hearing it.

**index.phtml**

```
<form name="payo" action="/paymentAction/" method="post" >
    <div id="tabs"> 
        <div id="nav">
            <input type="radio" name="tab" class="div1" value="Inv" /> Invoice &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tab" class="div2" value="CC" /> Credit Card &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tab" class="div3" value="Cpn"/> Coupon                                
        </div>

        <div id="div1" class="tab">
            <!-- INVOICE TEXT -->
        </div>

        <div id="div2" class="tab">
            <!-- CREDIT CARD FORM -->
            Credit Card Number: <input type=text name="CardNo" placeHolder="Credit Card Number" value="" maxlength="16"> 
            Expiration Month / Year: <font color="red">* </font> 
            <select name="ExpMonth">
                <option value=""selected>mm</option>
                <option >01</option>
                <option >02</option>
                <option >03</option>
            </select>
            <select name ="ExpYear">
                <option value=""selected>yy</option>
                <option >12</option>
                <option >13</option>
                <option >14</option>
            </select>
            Street Address Associated With Card: <input type=text name="Address" placeHolder="Address" value="">
        </div>

        <div id="div3" class="tab">
            <!-- COUPON FORM -->
            Coupon Code: 
            <input type="text" name="cpA" size=4 maxlength=4 > -
            <input type="text" name="cpnB" size=6 maxlength=6> -
            <input type="text" name="cpnC" size=5  maxlength=5>
            <br />
        </div>    

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            (function(){
                var tabs =document.getElementById('tabs');
                var nav = tabs.getElementsByTagName('input');

                function hideTabs(){
                    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = "none";
                }

                function showTab(tab){
                    document.getElementById(tab).className = 'tab';
                }

                hideTabs(); 

                for(var i=0;i<nav.length;i++){
                    nav[i].onclick = function(){
                        hideTabs();

                        var radios = document.getElementsByName('tab');
                        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                            if (radios[i].checked) {
                                var here = i;
                            }
                        }        
                        if (radios[here].value == "Inv") {   
                            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";     
                        } else if(radios[here].value == "CC") {
                            document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
                        } else if(radios[here].value == "Cpn") {
                            document.getElementById('div3').style.display = "block"; 
                        } else {

                        }    
                    }
                }
            })();
        </script>                              
        <div id="formdiv">
            <center><input type=submit name="submit" class="ButtonMain" value=" Authorize Payment "></center>
            <br />
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... please space the js better.... It is very hard to read.

Comment: What versions of IE ? What's your header and doctype ?

Comment: That stray `</center>` closing tag should be removed.

Comment: i think it works in IE9, check if your ie does not run in compatibility mode

Comment: Neal - Spacing fixed.
dystroy - IE 9, I've tried a variety nothing seems to work, but I'm open to suggestions!
Pointy - That's just bad transcribing on my part, tried to cut out unrelated code. 
tmpmember - I need this to work in IE's "default." And probably back to IE 7.

Comment: doctype: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fetch all inputs *including* the form inputs (card number et al.):

```
var nav = tabs.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Then you assign an `onclick` to each the first act of which is to hide the tabs then reshow them, so whenever any input is clicked focus is lost immediately.

Chrome will not do anything noticeable & restores the elements focus, IE will reset it so the element effectively becomes uncapturable.

You need to only manage changing tabs when the radio button is clicked;

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('tab');
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
   radios[i].onclick = function(){
```

Comment: Thank you Alex K. That was exactly the problem. I didn't think it through. If you are familiar with Snoopy's "Happy Dance" you know where I'm at.

Answer (score 2):

The issue looks like the line:

```
var nav = tabs.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

`nav` includes not just the radio buttons, but also the text input boxes as well, so when you attach the `onclick` function to all elements of the `nav` array it's causing the problem you see with the cursor jumping around. Quickest and easiest solution would be to limit it only to the radio buttons within the `div id="nav"` element:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Not required to fix the problem, but you can also simplify the javascript a little, since `radios` is not necessary anymore. Inside the `onclick` function, `this` will refer to the radio button clicked, so you can simplify:

```
nav[i].onclick = function(){
    hideTabs();
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('tab');
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            var here = i;
        }
    }        
    if (radios[here].value == "Inv") {   
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";     
    } else if(radios[here].value == "CC") {
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
    } else if(radios[here].value == "Cpn") {
        document.getElementById('div3').style.display = "block"; 
    } else {

    }
}
```

to:

```
nav[i].onclick = function(){
    hideTabs();

    if (this.value == "Inv") {   
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";     
    } else if(this.value == "CC") {
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
    } else if(this.value == "Cpn") {
        document.getElementById('div3').style.display = "block"; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out the simplification you suggested. Much appreciated. I completely missed the input - onclick relationship I established.